# how to get the value from mysql database and append the data to the textarea using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, mysql, jsp

I have written a program in jsp to get the values of 5 fields (name , age , email , phone , text) where my parameter will be name itself

jdbc code for the above :

```
public List getUserDetailsByName(String user_name) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        prep = (PreparedStatement) connection
                .prepareStatement("Select user_name , user_age , mobile_no , 
                 email_id , ck_text from user_details where user_name='"
                        + user_name + "'");
        rSet = prep.executeQuery();
        while (rSet.next()) {
            String name = rSet.getString(1);
            String age = rSet.getString(2);
            String email_id = rSet.getString(3);
            String mobile_no = rSet.getString(4);
            String ck_text = rSet.getString(5);
            list.add(name);
            list.add(age);
            list.add(email_id);
            list.add(mobile_no);
            list.add(ck_text);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Jsp code :userdetails_json.jsp

```
<%
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONObject finalJSON = new JSONObject();
Sql_Server details = new Sql_Server();
request.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");
String user_name = request.getParameter("user_name");
response.setContentType("application/json");
List<String> list = details.getUserDetailsByName(user_name);
int recordCounter = 1;
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject formDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
    formDetailsJson.put("name", list.get(i));
    formDetailsJson.put("age", list.get(++i));
    formDetailsJson.put("phone", list.get(++i));
    formDetailsJson.put("email", list.get(++i));
    formDetailsJson.put("ck_text", list.get(++i));
    finalJSON.put(recordCounter, formDetailsJson);
    ++recordCounter;
}

out.print(finalJSON.toString());
```

%>

When i insert a parameter in the url , as ?user_name="arjun" , i get json view as

```
{
 1: {
 phone: "123456789",
 email: "abc@gmail.com",
 age: "20",
 name: "arjun",
 ck_text: "<html> <head> <title></title> </head> <body>india lose 9th    
 wicket.</body> </html> "
   }
}
```

Now i have a listview in html page which has the four parameters name , age , email , phone , which i am getting through the above jsp code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $.ajax({ 
                type: 'GET', 
                url: 
           'http://localhost:8082/JqueryForm/html/jsp/userdetails_json.jsp', 
                data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) { 
                    $.each(data, function(i) {
                        var name = data[i].name;
                        var age = data[i].age;
                        var email = data[i].email;
                        var phone = data[i].phone;
                        console.log("name:" + name);
                        console.log("age:" + age);
                        console.log("email:" + email);
                        console.log("phone:" + phone);
                        var tr = $('<tr/>');
                        tr.append("<td><a href='user_details.html' 
                                 id='name'>" + name + "</a></td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + age + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + email + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + phone + "</td>");
                        $("#table").append(tr); 
                    });
                }
            });


    });
```

The list of records i am viewing in a table looks like this

Name    Age       Email                Phone

arjun   25  abc@gmail.com            123456789

bharat  31  xyz@gmail.com            456789012

Now what i want to do is , i have made the name as href , so when i click on arjun or bharat , a new page is opening in which i have 4 textareas to display the details of specific name , if i click on arjun , my new page should have only details of arjun which i want and is not displaying .
I have tried writing some code in jquery but i know i am going wrong somewhere , so need some help please

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#name").click(function() {
    var inputElem = $('#user_details :input[name="name"]');
    var username = inputElem.val();
    console.log("Param Value:"+user_name);
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 
        'http://localhost:8082/JqueryForm/html/jsp/userdetails_json.jsp',
        data : {
            user_name : username
        },
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i) {
                var name = data[i].name;
                var age = data[i].age;
                var email = data[i].email;
                var phone = data[i].phone;
                console.log("name:" + name);
                console.log("age:" + age);
                console.log("email:" + email);
                console.log("phone:" + phone);
            });
        }
    });

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Change your first Ajax request like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $.ajax({ 
            type: 'GET', 
            url: 'http://localhost:8082/JqueryForm/html/jsp/userdetails_json.jsp', 
            data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) { 
                $.each(data, function(i) {
                    var name = data[i].name;
                    var age = data[i].age;
                    var email = data[i].email;
                    var phone = data[i].phone;
                    console.log("name:" + name);
                    console.log("age:" + age);
                    console.log("email:" + email);
                    console.log("phone:" + phone);
                    var tr = $('<tr/>');
                    tr.append("<td><a href='#' class='username' data-name='" + name + "' data-age='" + age + "' data-email='" + email + "' data-phone='" + phone + "'>" + name + "</a></td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + age + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + email + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + phone + "</td>");
                    $("#table").append(tr); 
                });
            }
        });

        // And right a `onclick` function for anchor tag with class `username`, like:
        $("#username").on('click', function() {
            var queryString = 'name='+ $(this).attr('data-name');
            queryString += '&age='+ $(this).attr('data-age');
            queryString += '&email='+ $(this).attr('data-email');
            queryString += '&phone='+ $(this).attr('data-phone');

            var secondWindow = window.open("user_details.jsp?"+ queryString, "userdetails", "");
            secondWindow.focus();
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

And then you can display these fields on `user_details.jsp` from request,

```
<%
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String age = request.getParameter("age");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
%>
```

If you want keep `user_details.jsp` as html page like `user_details.html` then use jQuery's `$.query()` function to get request parameters.

Hope it helps, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying sir ,  instead of user_details.jsp , i have changed it to user_details.html , but sir when i click on the name arjun , the user_details.html page is not opening

Comment: Check for any JavaScript errors in browser and check the edited answer once.